# How do I set up and implement HTTP method for authorization?

Tags: ios, http, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get into a webAPI my classmate created with my iphone APP I've created. Right now, it connects, but my app just crashes because it tells me that I need authorization. So if for example, the username is abc and password abc123, How would I implement the HTTP method specifically to get passed authorization??

```
NSString *geturl = @"http://192.168.1.96:50364/api/transaction" ;
setValue:(NSString*)" " forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString*)username;
getjson *mds=[[getjson alloc] init];
SEL selector = @selector(addData:);
[mds setDirectionsQuery:geturl
           withSelector:selector
           withDelegate:self];
```

Edit: if the above problem is too confusing, what is the basic syntax/code for setting up the value and the key for username and password? I am sure

```
setValue:(NSString*)"abc " forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString*)username; 
setValue:(NSString*)"abc123 " forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString*)password;
```

is not correct. compiler is not letting me run the program.

Comment: Are you talking about HTTP Basic Authentication? Could you please provide your full code so far?

Comment: Yes HTTP Basic Authentication. My file is too big to provide. I have another getjson.m file where I implement the serialization.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/basic_authentication_iphone_cocoa_touch where you will find the example code for the http basic authentication. You will need to copy that `Base64` class implementation to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are missing `@`
Try `setValue:(NSString*)@"abc " forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString*)username;` although if the code you pasted is complete, it doesn't say what your setting values to.

I personally use NSMutableRequest and create the request and authorisation like this. Note that the auth gets Base64 encoded:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlString]];
NSString *basicAuthCredentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password;
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", AFBase64EncodedStringFromString(basicAuthCredentials)];
[urlRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: thank you sir, i just realized the web url will be in https, how should i implement the connection method differently?

Comment: The same way, just use https in your URL. Take a look at using AFNetworking, it makes these things so much easier https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking